# swap summation and multiple

Tags: summation, products

In which case can we swap summation and multiple? ie.
$$\sum_{i=1}^n\prod_{j=1}^na_{ij}=\prod_{j=1}^n\sum_{i=1}^na_{ij}$$
if we can't swap like this, please tell me how can we swap them?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Take for example the case $n=2$.  Then you are asking under what conditions we have
$$ab+cd=(a+c)(b+d)\ .$$
Likewise, if $n=3$ you are asking whether
$$abc+def+ghi=(a+d+g)(b+e+h)(c+f+i)\ .$$
These will only be true for very special values of $a,b,\ldots,i$ and in general there will be no way to swap the sum and product.

Answer (score 2):

Let me take the case for $n=3$ using your notations $$\sum_{i=1}^n\prod_{j=1}^na(i,j)=\prod_{j=1}^n\sum_{i=1}^na(i,j)$$ After expansion of sum and product, the lhs write $$a(1,1) a(1,2) a(1,3)+a(2,1) a(2,2) a(2,3)+a(3,1) a(3,2) a(3,3)$$ while the rhs write $$(a(1,1)+a(2,1)+a(3,1)) (a(1,2)+a(2,2)+a(3,2)) (a(1,3)+a(2,3)+a(3,3))$$ As you see, they do not have much to to with eachother and, as said by David, you cannot swap sum and product.

Answer (score 0):

- You can swap summations with summations.
- You can swap multiplications with multiplications.
- You cannot swap summation and multiplication.
- A fixed term can go outside of summation or into summation, but a fixed term cannot do so in multiplication.
- If you can do a 'log' value of a term, you can turn multiplication into summation.